# External dropdown not filtering datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a page which has a filter `dropdown` on and the `options` in this `dropdown`  are populated from my `JQuery Datatable`

The issue I am having is that when I select a value from the `dropdown` is not rendering anything.

I'm new to `Datatables` and I need the `dropdown` to be external NOT using the DT one.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        <select id="select" class="form-control">
            <option id="default">Please select</option>
        </select>
        <table id="manageDialPlanMainDataTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Number</th>
                    <th>Number type</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px"></th>
                    <th style="width: 100px"></th>
                    <th style="width: 100px"></th>
                    <th style="width: 130px"></th>
                    <th style="width: 200px"></th>
                    <th style="width: 200px"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var manageDialPlanMainDataTable = $('#manageDialPlanMainDataTable').DataTable({
    "ordering": true,
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    "info": false,
    "pagingType": 'simple_numbers',
    "pageLength": 10,
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "type": 'GET',
        "url": '../_IncomingCallCode/jsons/manageDpMainTable.json',
        "data": function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        "error": function () {
            $('#manageDialPlanMainDataTable_wrapper').hide();
            $('#existingRuleLoadErrorMessage').html(
                '<p>There was an issue retrieving data. Please try again.</p>' +
                '<p>If the error keeps occurring, please get in touch.</p>').addClass('text-danger');
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data) {
                telNumberSelected = data.telnum;
                strippedTelNo = telNumberSelected.split('-')[0];

                if ($.isNumeric(strippedTelNo)) {
                    strippedTelNo = '0' + strippedTelNo;

                    return strippedTelNo;
                } else {
                    return strippedTelNo;
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "searchable": false,
            "sorting": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data) {
                telNumberSelected = data.telnum;

                if (telNumberSelected.includes('-')) {
                    var telNumberSelectedType = telNumberSelected.split('-')[1];
                    var option;

                    if (telNumberSelectedType == 'oo') {
                        telNumberSelectedType = 'Out of hours';

                        option = "<option>" + telNumberSelectedType + "</option>"
                        $('#select').append(option);

                        return telNumberSelectedType
                    } else if (telNumberSelectedType == 'w') {
                        telNumberSelectedType = 'Working hours';

                        option = "<option>" + telNumberSelectedType + "</option>"
                        $('#select').append(option);

                        return telNumberSelectedType
                    } else {
                        var telNumberSelectedTypeOriginal = telNumberSelectedType;

                        // Add space between capitals if value doesn't have one
                        telNumberSelectedType = telNumberSelectedType.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
                        // Lowercases second word
                        telNumberSelectedType = telNumberSelectedType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + telNumberSelectedType.substr(1).toLowerCase();

                        option = "<option>" + telNumberSelectedType + "</option>"
                        $('#select').append(option);

                        return telNumberSelectedType
                    }
                } else {
                    telNumberSelectedType = 'N/A';

                    option = "<option>" + telNumberSelectedType + "</option>"
                    $('#select').append(option);

                    return telNumberSelectedType
                }
            },
            "createdCell": function (td) {
                // Populates each Num Type' TD with a 'Name'
                if (telNumberSelected.includes('-')) {
                    var telNoSelectedType = telNumberSelected.split("-").pop();
                    var telNoSelectedType = '-' + telNoSelectedType;

                    $(td).attr('name', telNoSelectedType);
                } else {
                    telNoSelectedType= 'N/A';

                    $(td).attr('name', telNoSelectedType);
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "initComplete": function () {
        var selectedNumType = {};

        // Removes duplicate values
        $('#select > option').each(function () {
            if (selectedNumType[this.value]) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                selectedNumType[this.value] = this.text;
            }
        });
    }
});

// Function call when Filter dropdown changed
$('#select').on('change', function () {
    var abc = this.value;
    var def = telNumberSelectedType;
    var aaa = $("#select option:selected").text();

    console.log('abc: ' + abc);
    console.log('def: ' + def);
    console.log('aaa: ' + aaa);

    if (abc != 'Please select') {
        manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search(abc).draw();
    } else {
        alert('ELSE');
        manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search('').draw();
    }
});
```

**DevTools screenshot for console.log's**

[image]

**Screenshot of rendered table**

[image]

[image]

I have tried changing the `columns(1)` number and also tried `column(1)` (No 's'), but I think I must be doing something completely wrong.

Basically I'm after:

- Dropdown `options` to be populated with the options displayed in the '2nd' column
- Filter the table when option matches the filter

My `else` is working though, if I re-select 'Please select' it redraws the entire table.

Comment: I think this can be closed under the official reason of Typo: _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me being the 'copy' and 'paste' king i am lol, I removed it from the 1st column but not the 2nd.  The code that was stopping it was:

```
"searchable": false,
"sorting": false,
"orderable": false,
```

From the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

on the following bit

```
// Function call when Filter dropdown changed
$('#select').on('change', function () {
    var abc = this.value;
    var def = telNumberSelectedType;
    var aaa = $("#select option:selected").text();

    console.log('abc: ' + abc);
    console.log('def: ' + def);
    console.log('aaa: ' + aaa);

    if (abc != 'Please select') {
        manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search(abc).draw();
    } else {
        alert('ELSE');
        manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search('').draw();
    }
});
```

try changing

```
manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search(abc).draw();
```

to

```
manageDialPlanMainDataTable.columns(1).search(aaa).draw();
```

See if that solves the problem. Please let me know if not and I will check again.